# Javascript,Jquery:How to add and delete elem autoly with CheckBox in one div，and elem displays in another div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs. One has three elems(John,Snow,Stock).Before each elem,there is a checkbox.Once John is checked,it will display in staff div.When John is unchecked,It is gone. When elems is checked to add_sub(e), it works fine. Once unchecked, it failed which is displays **Nana**.

My div code :

```
<div id="role_div">
<table >
<td style="word-break:break-all;"><input type="checkbox" name="uId" value="John">John</td>
<td style="word-break:break-all;"><input type="checkbox" name="uId" value="Snow">Snow</td>
<td style="word-break:break-all;"><input type="checkbox" name="uId" value="Stock">Stock</td>
</table>
</div>
<div id="staff" onclick="this.focus();"></div>
```

my js code:

```
var staff = document.getElementById("staff");
function add_sub(el) {
    if (el.checked){
        currNum += el.value+'<br />';
    } else {
        currNum -= el.value+'<br />';
    }
    staff.value = currNum;
}

form.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
        if(ev.target.getAttribute("type") == "checkbox"){
            add_sub(ev.target);
        }
    },false);
}    `
```

My code is not the best way.Who can help me ?

Comment: currNum in function add_sub() is not defined. You are using it before it has some value.

Comment: i have define currNum. var currNum="" ;
  var selected_user = document.getElementById("selected_user");
     var form = document.getElementById("transmit_form"); 
  
 function add_sub(el){

Comment: when unselect,selected_user.value will disapppear the elements.<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> e<br />

Comment: Please share the HTML and entire JS code, to better understand this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hava solved this problem;

```
var currNum="" ;
var selected_staff = document.getElementById("selected_staff");
//var form = document.getElementById("transmit_form"); 
function add_sub(el)
{
  if (el.checked)
  {
   //alert(el.value);
   selected_staff.innerHTML += el.value+'<br />';
  // selected_staff.innerHTML=currNum; 
  selectedStaff.value = selected_staff.innerHTML;
  alert(selectedStaff.value);
  }
  else
  {
    // currNum -= el.value;
    var strReplace = el.value+'<br>';
    //alert(strReplace);
    selected_staff.innerHTML = selected_staff.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(strReplace,"g"),"");
    selectedStaff.value = selected_staff.innerHTML;
    alert(selectedStaff.value);
  }

}
staff_div.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
if(ev.target.getAttribute("type") == "checkbox"){
    add_sub(ev.target);
    }
},false);
```